# Unable to connect to internet from within a Linux VM

Tags: linux, vmware, virtualization

I have an Oracle Enterprise Linux 64bit VM running on my Windows 7 64bit machine. I have enabled the NAT as my network adapter, however I am still not able to connect to internet from within the machine.

Inside linux the `eth0` shows as up

Please note that I am within an Office network and have installed the VMware tools

Comment: I had the same problem. It happened when the host connected to the LAN *after* the VM was launched.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably one of the following:

- For some reason the guest doesn't get an IP from the artificial DHCP provided by vmware
- You have an over-zealous firewall